# How to split a binary string?

Tags: split, bit

i want to implement a function in python that splits a n binary string like this:
input: [00, 01, 10, 11]
output: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
for any number os bits in the input array.

I tried this way:

```
    split_bin = []
    setnum = []
    for i in range(0, len(num_bin)):
        for k in range(0, n):
            setnum.append(split_bin[i] & 1<<k)

    return setnum
```

Comment: Are the types of the elements of the input array strings?

Comment: integers in binary form

Comment: Is `[b'101', b'111', b'01', b'11', b'0']` a valid input?

Comment: no, all the values have to be in the same length. In this case the input would be: 
[b'101', b'111', b'001', b'011, b'000] but i alredy made a function that make this transformation.

Comment: def dec_to_bin(num, n): \n 

    num_bin = bin(num)[2:].zfill(n) \n 
    
return num_bin

Comment: filling up the number with 0's to the left depending on n

Comment: sorry for my english, still learning

Answer (score 0):

The function you provided in the comments:

```
def dec_to_bin(num, n): 
    num_bin = bin(num)[2:].zfill(n) 
    return num_bin
```

returns a string, not binary, but that is ok; we can still split it like you want.

```
input = ['00', '01', '10', '11']
output = []

for number in input:
    output.append([bit for bit in number])

print(output)
# [['0', '0'], ['0', '1'], ['1', '0'], ['1', '1']]
```